# How to change cursor color in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Dears, 
   I have 2 qestions in flutter If you don't mind.

**1- How to change the color of the cursor as it default blue and I don't like it**

**2- how can I make the text at the bottom of the screen whatever the screen size. ??**

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand the second question, do you want to the stretch the Text dynamically with the screen size? You can get the value of screen width and go from there, here's the code:

    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width

Comment: @mirkancal I don't want to stretch  the text. I want to make it's position at the end of the screen

Answer (score 72):

put  `cursorColor: Colors.white,` inside the TextFormField

Comment: This feature is deprecated

Comment: This feature has been removed. Use `textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData( cursorColor: Colors.white)` instead.

Answer (score 59):

This works fine in both iOS and Android:

```
TextField(cursorColor: Colors.white)
```

But, if you like to set it in theme then

**SOLUTION 1** - Original answer, recently not tested, also, seems it's deprecated:

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14598#issuecomment-485218728):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

MaterialApp(
  title: "Rate your Colleagues",
  theme: ThemeData(
    // for iOS
    cupertinoOverrideTheme: CupertinoThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.red,
    ),
    // for others(Android, Fuchsia)
    cursorColor: Colors.red,
    home: SplashScreen(),
  );
  ...
```

**SOLUTION 2** - edited answer - not tested - please give credit to @i4guar

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14598#issuecomment-485218728):

```
MaterialApp(
  title: "Rate your Colleagues",
  theme: ThemeData(
     textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
        cursorColor: darkPrimarySwatchColor,
        selectionColor: darkPrimarySwatchColor,
        selectionHandleColor: darkPrimarySwatchColor,
     ),
   ),
   home: SplashScreen(),
 );
```

Comment: your first solution works fine for me, but setting `cursorColor` in the theme is not working.

Comment: cursorColor in ThemeData has been deprecated., any other solution.

Comment: look at the comments below e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65550345/9142902

Comment: The first solution is deprecated, `textSelectionTheme` should be used instead.

Answer (score 26):

`cursorColor` is now deprecated for `ThemeData` use this instead (works on both iOS and android):

```
MaterialApp(
  title: "Rate your Colleagues",
  theme: ThemeData(
     textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
        cursorColor: darkPrimarySwatchColor,
        selectionColor: darkPrimarySwatchColor,
        selectionHandleColor: darkPrimarySwatchColor,
     ),
   ),
   home: SplashScreen(),
 );
```

Comment: Yes this is should be the accepted answer for the question #1.

Answer (score 22):

Flutter has been updated, and now the **cursorColor** is used like this:

```
ThemeData(
  ...
  textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
    cursorColor: Colors.blue, //thereby
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 16):

For question 1 you can set the `cursorColor` for `theme` attribute when calling `MaterialApp` like the below

```
new MaterialApp(
  title: "Flutter App",
  theme: ThemeData(
    cursorColor: Colors.red,
    home: HomeScreen(),
)
```

Comment: Does that actually work for anyone? Mine still defaults to blue, even if Theme.of(context).cursorColor is black...

Comment: @d0n.key Yes, you can also assign cursorColor property inside the TextField.

Comment: CursorColor  is Deprecated.

Comment: This is no longer a valid answer.

Answer (score 4):

I had to set `useTextSelectionTheme` to `true` and set textSelectionTheme for my custom dark theme:

```
ThemeData _defaultDarkTheme = ThemeData.dark();

ThemeData _darkTheme = initializeDefaultLineHeight(ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    // How to set cursor color for TextFormField
    useTextSelectionTheme: true,
    textSelectionTheme: _defaultDarkTheme.textSelectionTheme.copyWith(
        cursorColor: Colors.grey[600]),
```

Comment: `useTextSelection` theme was required for `textSelectionTheme` to work. Thanks!

Comment: Real mvp answer here ! `useTextSelectionTheme: true` made it work!

Comment: `useTextSelection` theme isn't required any more