# TextFormField - How to change cursor color

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm would like to change the cursor color in a `TextFormField`.

I don't find the `Property`.

To know I'm on a Flutter web app and not mobile.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change TextField cursor color in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65897342/how-to-change-textfield-cursor-color-in-flutter)

Comment: Yes, finally that was easy to do ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65898579/14434426) answer:

> You can change specific textfield cursor color for your solution:
>
> TextField(cursorColor: Colors.white)
>
> but if you want to change it completely in your project then you can
> check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55991901/how-to-change-cursor-color-in-flutter) here