# flutter : How to change selectetion cursor color

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I want to change green selection cursor how will to do this.

that green color is matching with background image. and i want to change into white color which is in circle.

[image]

this is code

```
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 8, 40, 20),
              child: Theme(
                data: new ThemeData(

                  primaryColor: Colors.red,
                  accentColor: Colors.orange,
                  hintColor: Colors.white,
                  inputDecorationTheme: new InputDecorationTheme(
                      labelStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
                ),
                child: TextFormField(

                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  cursorColor: Colors.white,
                  controller: nameController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  enabled: isNameEdit,
                  // enableInteractiveSelection: false,

                  focusNode: focusNode,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
                    ),
                  ),
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: t1Size,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Could you post the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change cursor color in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55991901/how-to-change-cursor-color-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

In the class that runs in the

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const <your_class>());
}
```

add textSelectionTheme to ThemeData

```dart
class <your_class> extends StatelessWidget {
  const <your_class>({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        // add this
        textSelectionTheme:
            const TextSelectionThemeData(selectionHandleColor: Colors.white),
      ),
      home: const <your_home_class>(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this is not working

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Yes I knew it from here but Can't I do this, can I change the color of the textfield on the ThemeData, without doing anything on the homepage?