# How to change cursor color in TextField Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, material-design, textfield

I'm facing the problem that my cursor color isn't changing when wrapping TextField by Theme widget.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/q/55991901/10157127

Comment: @YeasinSheikh no, it's about pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here is that pointer color isn't changing while wrapping directly. It's mentioned in this thread https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/74890

What you can do, is add Theme in your MaterialApp widget

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
          selectionColor: Colors.green,
          cursorColor: Colors.green,
          selectionHandleColor: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
      home: const HomeWidget(),
    );
  }
```

and your TextField will look like this:

```
class _SimpleTextFieldState extends State<SimpleTextField> {
  Color focusColor = Colors.grey;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Focus(
      onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
          focusColor = Colors.green;
        } else {
          focusColor = Colors.grey;
        }
        setState(() {});
      },
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          isDense: true,
          labelText: 'Text',
          labelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: focusColor,
            fontSize: fontSize15,
          ),
          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
          ),
          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
          ),
          border: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
          ),
        ),
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: fontSize15,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

inactive

[image: PriceField inactive]

active

[image: PriceField active]

Comment: I faced a HUGE problem doing it in flutter module connected to native app that cursor color wasn't changing dynamically even when variable was changed, so the only solution that I saw is adding your custom TextSelectionControls

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 :-

```
FYI:- Add "cursorColor" property in theme data

    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    MaterialApp(
      title: "Solution 1",
      theme: ThemeData(
        cursorColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: splashScreen(),
    );
```

Solution 2 :-

```
 MaterialApp(
  title: "Solution 2",
  theme: ThemeData(
     textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
        cursorColor: darkPrimarySwatchColor,
        selectionColor: darkPrimarySwatchColor,
        selectionHandleColor: darkPrimarySwatchColor,
     ),
   ),
   home: splashScreen(),
 );
```